# Change Default Unity 3D Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I have a standard asset First Person Controller, with its Main Camera. I added in 2 other cameras to use with render textures. However, when I debug it uses the other camera, not the Main Camera with the FPC. Is it possible to select which camera is used?

Comment: Have you assigned render textures to be the target of those other cameras? Then it should not render those cameras to frame buffer.

Comment: Not as of yet, I didn't think of that because I have no planes to assign them too yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point cameras are rendering on top of each other. So you are seeing only the last camera.

If you don't want to assign render textures yet, then you need to disable cameras you are not using. This can be done by unchecking a checkbox next to "Camera" component. Or you can disable them with a script.

[image: Camera disabling]

On the other hand, if you want to render all of them to the screen, you can change `x`, `y`, `h` and `w` values do to that.

Comment: I plan to use them as CCTV Cameras, so they'll be used as render textures.